# Hexdecimal to String and vice versa

Tags: javascript, hex

How does this site does its conversion?
http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal

For example. If I convert string:

"㐤㐥" => "e3 90 a4 e3 90 a5"

"e3 90 a4 e3 90 a5" => "㐤㐥"

"e390a4e390a5" => "㐤㐥" (still works)

I thought it was stirng.charCodeAt and convert each one to to hex format: I get "3424 3425", so that's not it... what am I missing?

Comment: It does the conversion on the backend, not the frontend, which means the exact mechanism is not visible to us; check your Network tab and the site's JS: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/js/main.js

Comment: Hint: UTF8 is kind of standard.